# Jagged font on Windows - Chrome & Safari

Tags: css, cross-browser, font-face

I'm using custom fonts on my webpage using the following code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeueBold';
    src: url('fonts/HelveticaNeueBold.eot');
    src: url('fonts/HelveticaNeueBold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/HelveticaNeueBold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/HelveticaNeueBold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/HelveticaNeueBold.svg#HelveticaNeueBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

This works fine across all browsers on Mac but looking at it on PC on Chrome and Safari it appears jagged. Are there any fixes I could use to make it all look the same? Below shows the difference (Mac on left, PC on right - both on Chrome).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@font-face fonts on PC generally look a little more ropey, but 'Hinting' the fonts will improve readability.

Try running your fonts through the font squirrel convertor, which can process the hinting as part of the conversion.

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

As a side note I'd also just not use @font-face for Helvetica, and just rely on people having the font installed, falling back to Arial. Not the closest match, but it will give you the best result.

Comment: Thanks. I used to use fontsquirrel but then moved to a piece of software called FontXchange. It's never failed me up until now (I've converted hundreds of fonts) so perhaps I need to use a combination of the two if the font is looking a little ropey.

Answer (score 2):

It appears Chrome does not like the SVG to be called last in the CSS @font-face declaration. Add this after your @font-face { ... } in your CSS:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeueBold';
    src: url('fonts/HelveticaNeueBold.svg') format('svg');
  }
}
```

The @media query targets webkit browsers and tells them to solely utilize the .SVG file. In my experience this improves rendering on Windows Chrome.

CAUTION: This fix could cause another problem in Chrome on Windows 7 or 8, which I have encountered on some occasions: Utilizing this fix sometimes prevents word-wrapping in Chrome on Windows. A very strange behaviour which only occurs sometimes and I have not found a solution for. A question about this has been posted here:

[Strange word length issue when using font-face in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054633/strange-word-length-issue-when-using-font-face-in-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-0.0000000001deg);
```

This rotates the element just enough to make the browser render it anti-aliased. Don't know what it does for performance, but I didn't notice any difference in rendering.

Solution found here: https://twitter.com/#!/komejo/statuses/117241707522818048

Comment: 19. It does rotate the text, I just don't see the antialiasing turning off.

Comment: It used to work, only for bigger font sizes though. Seems not to work anymore. :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are. Use an alternative like [cufon](https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki) for smooth fonts.

Comment: Is there no fix for font-face?

Comment: Cufon looks fuzzy on retina devices.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what OS you are using, but you may need to enable ClearType for screen fonts.

In XP: go to the **Display** control panel, and select the **Appearance** tab. From there, click **Effects**. Select the **Use the following method to smooth edges of screen fonts** checkbox, and then select **ClearType** in the list.

That has solved the problem for me in the past.

Comment: Although that would solve the problem for me, what about the thousands of visitors to the website?

Answer (score 0):

This is a fundamental difference between how Windows and OS X handle font rendering, so there is little you can do. One hacky fix for Chrome is adding a nearly invisible drop shadow (`text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .01) 0 0 1px`) which forces it to antialias the text. Services like Typekit are working hard to fix the problem, such as [serving fonts as Postscript outlines](http://blog.typekit.com/2011/08/31/improved-windows-rendering-for-adobe-fonts/), but that doesn't help your problem very much.

Comment: This solution doesn't work anymore, see http://taitems.tumblr.com/post/7107609467/font-face-smoothing-in-windows-chrome

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```
html {
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: .10px;
}
```