# Strange word length issue when using font-face in Chrome

Tags: css, font-face

I have an extremely strange issue that occasionally happens when viewing a site in Chrome. You can see the issue happening in the image below:

[image: This is the issue happening]

It looks like an overflow / word-break / word-wrap CSS issue, but it definitely isn't. I know this because if I change the font to a standard font like Helvetica in Chrome's dev console, it sort's itself out and goes back to normal, like below:

[image: Back to normal]

If I change it back to the font-face type, it then all works ok! It is a very strange problem this. It only occasionally happens, and I haven't seen it happen in any browser other than Chrome. It seems like Chrome is struggling to calculate the length of the words using the font or something. It happens for every element on the page as well, not just the paragraphs in the images above.

This is the CSS for the font-face:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'gotham_lightregular';
    src: url('/ekmps/shops/lm_boutique/resources/Other/gotham-light-webfont.eot.txt');
    src: url('/ekmps/shops/lm_boutique/resources/Other/gotham-light-webfont.eot.txt?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/ekmps/shops/lm_boutique/resources/Other/gotham-light-webfont.svg.txt#gotham_lightregular') format('svg'),
         url('/ekmps/shops/lm_boutique/resources/Other/gotham-light-webfont.ttf.txt') format('truetype'),
         url('/ekmps/shops/lm_boutique/resources/Other/gotham-light-webfont.woff.txt') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

**EDIT**

[This is the site I am working on.](http://www.lamaisonboutique.co.uk/index.asp) But I'm not sure if it will help as the problem isn't currently occuring, it's hard to catch it when it's happening.

Comment: Would be helpful if you have it in a fiddle, or on a test site of sorts.

Comment: Yeah, can we please have a fiddle?

Comment: I'll place the link to the live site

Comment: It's not really such a good idea to have a custom font for your *entire* document:  http://superuser.com/questions/547743/why-dont-websites-immediately-display-their-text-these-days

Comment: The title of this question is not 'Is it a good idea to use a custom font on a website'

Comment: Its not unusual for comments to advise against doing *something stupid*.  If you don't like being told that you're doing *something stupid*, maybe you should avoid doing things that are stupid.  Nowhere did I state that your question was not worth answering, as it could potentially impact headlines or elements where a custom font would not be a poor choice.

Comment: @cimmanon I apologise for being rude yesterday, upon consideration I have come to the conclusion that you are probably right, using font-face for an entire document probably is a bit of a silly thing to do. It isn't something I've done before, but as the site I am working on is a personal thing, I had become slightly obsessed with the design (which is difficult for me as I am not a designer), and possibly lost sight of good practice in pursuit of said design.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and found it to be related to this style block that I had in my css document:

```
* {
    /* optimize text for legibility */
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

I was able to solve it by deleting the offending css and then adding this bit of jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $("body").css("text-rendering", "optimizeLegibility");
});
```

I think there must be a rendering issue in Chrome that causes this, but applying the optimizeLegibility style after the DOM is ready seems to fix the problem.